# Extracting session a key from a Facebook access token 

Tags: facebook, upload

What does this format of access token mean?

```
AAAEGXJapkeoBAGRlZC7aBLhiZBMMUEVZAAF68ZBhZBwD0ER1MwvkXlRUZCwOaczfgsGwHbnAYBcTU9VrPZCyYw3pIJmCIMZBxSnCPNGqPRWZALgZDZD
```

How can I get a session key from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an encrypted token and you can't get a session key from it. You'll need to move your application over to using the new GRAPH API.